# Matplotlib plotting slow

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am having csv files with big chunks of data that I am trying to plot using matplotlib ,but this is taking huge amount of time .Currently I have 292968 entries that need to be plotted.The program has been running for over 15 minutes and still no graph !!!`

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl 
arr = []
arr1 = []
with open('hello.csv') as cs :
    r = csv.reader(cs , delimiter = ',')
    i=0
    for row in r:
         if(i>4):
                arr.append(row[1])
                arr1.append(row[0])
         i+=1


print len(arr),len(arr1)
pl.plot(arr1 , arr)
pl.show()
```

Comment: What part takes the time? I assume filling the list in a loop is the slow part. Try using numpy or pandas to read the csv file

Comment: Filling the list is relatively quicker , maybe 2-3  seconds.Plotting is taking time

Comment: 292968 data points, and how many pixels are in your plot?

Comment: then what should be done to map all the points on the screen ?